# Preventative or Preventive?

Tags: contemporary-english

I continue to hear people use the word, "preventative."  I've always considered "preventive" to be correct. I consider the extra syllable in preventative to be superfluous. For example: With regard to medicine, we call it "preventive medicine," not preventative medicine. Which one is actually preferred in modern English?

Comment: related: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/preventive-versus-preventative

Answer (score 0):

*preventive* is the right word, because the verb is *prevent*, not *<strike>preventate</strike>*.

**EDIT:** On second thought, thanks to *sumelic*, the argumentation above is wrong. The usage of the *-ive* and *-ative* suffixes is [inconsistent](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/139488/77227), cf. *represent—representative*. I can only recommend that you prefer *preventive* for its brevity and idiomaticity.

Comment: By this logic, rather than "imaginative" we should say "imaginive".

Comment: @sumelic, I derive *imaginative* not from *imagine* but from *imagination*.

Comment: What about "talkative", then? There's no "talkate" or "talkation".

Comment: @sumelic, well-obeserved. My answer was hasty and ill-pondered. There must be a deeper rule governing the formation of adjectives from verbs, which I don't know—a law that prescribes the addition of *at* in *talkative* and proscribes it in *preventive*. I shall add this rule to my answer if I ever discover it.

Comment: I just found this interesting answer from Sven Yargs at the linked question: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/139488/77227 Based on the information there, it seems to me that the prescriptivist preference for "preventive" is based on the forms of the related Latin words.

Comment: @sumelic, very good answer. The example of *represent—representative* leaves no hope of establishing a consistent rule. I deserved the downvote.